# Request from C# to Apache: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, .net, apache, http, ubuntu

I have two linux Apache servers running behind load balancer. 
On both Apache server I have installed exactly the same installation of Yourls API for shortening URLs. I am sending request to that Yourls API to short URL.

Request to these servers are sent from C# production site, for shortening URLs.

It worked fine for months, and then suddenly on request I start receiving error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Nothing is changed in meanwhile. Apache server doesn't have any security restriction or something.

This code for request:

```
public dynamic SendRequest(string action, NameValueCollection parameters = null)
    {

        var client = new NoKeepAliveWebClient();
        string jsonResult = string.Empty;
        dynamic result;

        //we need to form url with requests
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["format"] = "json";
        data["action"] = action;
        data["signature"] = this.key;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in parameters)
            {
                data[key] = parameters[key];
            }
        }

        try
        {
            byte[] byteResult = client.UploadValues(url, data);
            jsonResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteResult);
            dynamic tempResult = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);

            result = tempResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error SendRequest (Action: {0}) Json: {1}      {2}",
                action,
                jsonResult,
                ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I am not getting this error for all request, but I am getting it for most of them.

I don't know anything about C#. I am responsible for Apache server, and I cannot find anything on those servers what can block those requests, or cause errors like this.

So my question is:
Does this can be caused by Apache server or it is specific for C#. Or maybe it have something with load balancer.

I guess that question is kind dumb, but I need to know asap which side is causing the problem.

**EDIT**

By adding more logs on C# side I got detailed errors.

```
 ErrorType: WebException  ErrorMessage: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.  
 InnerExceptionType: IOException InnerExceptionMessage: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

**EDIT**

I concluded that the problem is with load balancer (hproxy)

I have one server on which is installed hproxy. Hproxy serve two aplications servers. When I am sending requests over hproxy I am getting those errors.

Now I stopped using hproxy and I am calling requests directly to one aplications servers and it works fine now, without errors. But I need it works with hproxy.

So any idea, what in hproxy can cause those errors.

Comment: If it is HTTP, start to capture network packets.

Comment: It is HTTP, I tried with http 1.1 and 1.0 but the same case. Any sugestion hot to capture network packets in file, or something, because I am getting a lot of requests on my server

Comment: Are you familiar with network packet analysis? If so, you should be able to quickly identify which connection should be checked, and why this connection was closed (FIN or RST). That behavior on the wire can later be used to check which side (server, client, or proxy) was the cause.

Comment: I was tracking http packets and concluded that everything is fine with both apache servers. All http requests which comes on servers was handled fine. I concluded that the problem is with load balancer. 

I sopped sending requests over load balancer and start sending requests directly to one server and it works fine, without errors.

I am using hproxy for load balansing which is set up on third server. So when I am calling requests ove hproxy I am getting those errors.

So now I cannot find what is wrong with load balacer, what can cause those errors, any ideas?

Comment: When you identified the load balancer is the cause, did you also get the error pattern on how it breaks connections? For example, does it prematurely close connections? Does it reset connections after a certain timeout? With the patterns you can predict if some settings of it were wrongly configured.